# Why does this simple Swift generics construct fail to compile?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, generics

I'm working on my first Swift based project (xcode 6.3.2) and don't seem to get a simple generics construct to build.

The following seems to fail to compile on xcode 6.3.2 (compiler exit with code 1):

```
// with :AnyObject constraint => compiler crash
class GenericsTest : MyDelegate{

    static let instance = GenericsTest()

    private init(){
        var wrapper = MyWrapper<MyDelegate>(inner: self)

        if let md = wrapper.inner {
            println("delegate value \(md.someString)")
        }
    }

    // MyDelegate impl
    var someString = "my delegate impl"

}

protocol MyDelegate : class {
    var someString : String {get set}
}

class MyWrapper<T: AnyObject>{
    private (set) var inner : T?

    init(inner : T){
        self.inner = inner
    }

}
```

It looks like the Swift compiler does not like the :AnyObject type constraint of MyWrapper; the following code compiles and runs without any problem:

```
// no :AnyObject constraint
class GenericsTest : MyDelegate{

    static let instance = GenericsTest()

    private init(){
        var wrapper = MyWrapper<MyDelegate>(inner: self)

        if let md = wrapper.inner {
            println("delegate value \(md.someString)")
        }
    }

    // MyDelegate impl
    var someString = "my delegate impl"

}

protocol MyDelegate : class {
    var someString : String {get set}
}

class MyWrapper<T>{
    private (set) var inner : T?

    init(inner : T){
        self.inner = inner
    }

}
```

I need the :AnyObject type constraint because I'm actually trying to create a weak wrapper, which requires this constraint, like so:

```
// with weak wrapper and obligatory :AnyObject constraint (compiler crash)
class GenericsTest : MyDelegate{

    static let instance = GenericsTest()

    private init(){
        var wrapper = MyWrapper<MyDelegate>(inner: self)

        if let md = wrapper.inner {
            println("delegate value : \(md.someString)")
        }
    }

    // MyDelegate impl
    var someString = "my delegate impl"

}

protocol MyDelegate : class {
    var someString : String {get set}
}

class MyWrapper<T: AnyObject>{
    weak private (set) var inner : T?

    init(inner : T){
        self.inner = inner
    }

}
```

Anybody any idea how to work around this issue?

Comment: There is probably no problem in your code, the compiler just crashed. It's a bug in the compiler. Note the compiler is still very new.

Comment: @Sulthan Ok, thanks for verifying... I'm working around the issue for now by simply avoiding generics on all code using weak references, hope this gets resolved quickly.